# Do you write late son of Mr David or Son of late Mr David?

Tags: grammar

Do you write 'Late son of David or Son of late David? Which is correct?

Comment: It depends who died.

Comment: @mdewey - or who was tardy?

Answer (score 2):

Which one is *late*?

> The late son of Mr. David

means that the son is dead.

> The son of the late Mr. David

means that Mr. David is dead.

If an adjective modifies a proper name, we generally use *the* before it, as in the book title *The Inimitable Jeeves*.